# Can I decrease the scrolling speed (using touchpad) of Adobe Reader?

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, adobe-reader

I am using the latest version of Adobe Reader (DC 2017, it seems). Scrolling with a mouse is fine, but with the two-finger gesture on the touchpad (it is a Microsoft Precision touchpad, so it is not working by a propriety software) is too fast.

That is, just swiping down just one centimetre scrolls as much as one PDF screen (I am using Fit Width). As far as I tested, Adobe Reader is the only application that scrolls this fast. In fact, the two-finger scrolling is a little bit slow on other applications such as Google Chrome.

Is there any way to decrease the two-finger scrolling speed of Adobe Reader? Again, the scrolling speed is too fast **only** for Adobe Reader, so I do not want to decrease it system-wise.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer regarding the Adobe Reader but I feel I need to share it. First of all, I've noticed that some pdfs suffer from this issue while other pdfs don't. It seems there is no solution regarding this issue. Scrolling Adobe Reader with two fingers in Windows 10 is unstable. To enjoy this feature, open your pdfs with chrome or any other apps which support stable scrolling feature with two fingers. With chrome, you can scroll your pdfs documents with a reasonable speed.

Comment: It seemed that only large documents (those which have many pages) were affected. I had reported this at the Adobe's support forum, and I had found others have already reported the same thing, but Adobe seemed to be ignoring it.

Answer (score -1):

There is an option which you might try. Only got the german version in front of me right now but it should be under "View -> Page Display"... there's two options for single page/single page continous. On some PDFs using gestures just jumps around wildly but as soon as it's set to continous it works (for me) most of the time.

The option can also be set through preferences -> accessibility -> override page display.

Comment: I think there used to be "... continuous", but as of now, the names are (1)"Single Page View" and (2)"Enable Scrolling" = continuous scrolling. I have been using only (2), but when I changed it to (1), the scrolling speed was seriously decreased and the scrolling was jerky. It could be a little bit better than that "wild" scrolling, but it is still not so pleasant. I wish Adobe would fix this...